# php_info() showing curl.cainfo path with three X's at end but this isn't how it's set in php.ini

Tags: php, curl, wamp

**Background:** We've got a WAMP stack running Moodle and our H5P Hub access is failing with

> unable to get local issuer certificate

which is related to curl not being able to verify certificates from HTTPS requests because (I believe) it doesn't have access to the required trusted CA root certificates.

**Issue:**
We've taken a CA Bundle (`cacert.pem`) and placed it in `E:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.23\extras\ssl` and updated `php.ini` with the following: `curl.cainfo=E:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.23/extras/ssl/cacert.pem` and restarted Apache.

A look at php_info() however shows the value with three X's at the end:

[image: curl configuration settings in php_info()]

i.e. `E:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.23/extras/ssl/cacert.pemXXX`

Suffice to say, the opening issue hasn't been resolved.
Can anyone explain why the XXX appears and how I can resolve it?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: My first guess is unexpected whitespace. Maybe get a hex editor like XVI32 and take a look at that line. Maybe a different line ending or a Unicode partial or something.

Comment: I wondered similar, but the problem resolved itself after I pointed out to the stack admin that they had entered a full filepath into different but related setting "openssl.capath" (should be a directory, not a file)

Comment: You might want to have a look at moodle's bug tracker: https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-73588. Seems to have been fixed last week.